# Combinations function in Java

Tags: java, math, statistics

In one of the examples in my book it creates two methods. One called combinations and one called factorial. The body on the combinations method contains the following code

```
private int combinations(int n, int k){
  return factorial(n) / (factorial (k) * factorial (n-k));
    }
```

In an example of actually seeing how the math works out for this formula the textbook gives the following example. With n = 5 and k = 2. It gives the following steps and says you should get 10. I'm having difficulty understating the logic.

Does ! have a special meaning in this case? How does 5! = 120 and how does !2 x !3 = 2 x 6?

```
C (n,k)  =     n! 
           _________
           k! x (n - k)! 



C (5,2)  =     5! 
           ___________
             2! x !3 


         =   120 
           _________
             2 x 6 

         =  10
```

Comment: Wow. I feel stupid. I just read a section about using factorials. I just didn't connect the dots.

Comment: @YegorChumakov. And may be you shouldn't be talking so rude. You can even tell the same thing in a polite way.

Comment: @RohitJain maybe i've been too offensive, but i definitely advise Jessika to study some math, because it will be hard to she to go further in cs without it.

Comment: @YegorChumakov. Yeah that is true. And it is good to suggest what is correct. But just be polite, that's what I wanted to say. Anyways, it happens. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n!` means `factorial(n)`. It is equal to: -

```
n! = n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * .... * 1
```

So,

```
5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120
```

And `!3` is rather a typo in your book. It doesn't represent a `factorial`

Comment: I knew what it meant but for some reason it slipped my mind when I saw it in a formula.

Comment: @JessicaM.. Its ok. It happens. Many times the very obvious concept slips from your mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

! denotes a factorial.

```
5! = 120
```

because

```
5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

and

```
2! x 3! = 2 * 6
```

because

```
2! x 3! = (2 * 1) * (3 * 2 * 1)
```

[Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

Comment: I just read a section on factorials but it just slipped my mind that ! meant factorials.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` (factorial) symbol means the product of all integers up to and including the number. So, for example:

```
5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120
```

This should help clarify what the `factorial(int)` method is doing.

By the way, if your book actually printed "!3" instead of "3!", it's a typo.